# Subselect within select statement returning null

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

I'm trying to list the name of courses and their prereqs (if there are any) in a university database. The schema for these tables look like this

```
course(course_id, title, dept_name, credits)
prereq(course_id, prereq_id)
```

This is my query

```
SELECT title, (SELECT title
              FROM course NATURAL JOIN prereq c2
              WHERE c1.prereq_id = c2.course_id)
FROM course NATURAL LEFT JOIN prereq c1;
```

My results are returning null for all values of the second select statement. I have a feeling it has something to do with the value of c1 not being known at the time of the second select statement. Is there a way around this or a better query that can be used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm trying to list the name of courses and their prereqs (if there are
>   any) in a university database.

You can do this instead:

```
SELECT 
  c1.title "Course Title",
  IFNULL(c2.title, "Has No Preqs") "Preq Course Title"
FROM course c1
LEFT JOIN prereq p ON p.course_id = c1.course_id
LEFT JOIN course c2 ON p.prereq_id= c2.course_id
```

### [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d2245/9)

But this won't work in case there are many prerequisite courses for any course.

In this case you have to use `GROUP_CONCAT` as @danihp pointed out in his answer like so:

```
SELECT 
  c1.title "Course Title",
  GROUP_CONCAT(IFNULL(c2.title, "Has No Preqs")) "Preq Course Title"
FROM course c1
LEFT JOIN prereq p ON p.course_id = c1.course_id
LEFT JOIN course c2 ON p.prereq_id= c2.course_id
GROUP BY c1.title ;
```

### [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f88cb/3)

Comment: You should learn to copy answer. Right sentence is: `IFNULL(GROUP_CONCAT(c2.title), "Has No Preqs")` not `GROUP_CONCAT(IFNULL(c2.title, "Has No Preqs"))`.

Comment: @danihp - I didn't copy your answer. I pointed out to your answer in my answer. And `IFNULL(GROUP_CONCAT(c2.title), "Has No Preqs")` is also right.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for [group_concat](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) aggregation function:

```
SELECT 
   title,  
   group_concat( distinct c2.title ) as prereqs
FROM course 
NATURAL LEFT JOIN prereq c1
left outer join course c2 on c1.course_id = c2.course_id
group by course.course_id;
```